# How to balance consumer loads on asymmetric computer?

Tags: python, apache-kafka

I have a kafka prototype where I create

- 1 producer,
- 2 brokers,
- 2 consumers in the same group,
- 1 topic with 2 partitions.

Each consumer is assigned 1 partition.  The producer pushes 100 messages to the two brokers. Each consumer then pulls and processes 50 messages each. consumer#2 runs on a slow machine: it takes twice more time to process its assigned messages than consumer#1. Thus consumer#1 finishes its processing first and gets idle.

I'd like consumer#1 to pull some messages from consumer#2 so that to accelerate the processing. A regular shared Queue like `multiprocessing.queue` does that natively.

1. How can I balance consumer loads in such a usecase?

Answer (score 1):

You can add more partitions to the already created topic, let's say 4 partitions.

```
./kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper zk_host:port --alter --topic <topic-name> --partitions <num-partitions>
```

Then on the side of the consumer, you can specify from which partitions you want to consume. In this specific case, the fast consumer can consume from the partitions 0 to 2, and the slow computer only from the partition 3.

The process to perform a manual partition assignment on the consumer varies depending on the library you are using.

In Java you can check the [assign()](https://kafka.apache.org/0101/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html#assign(java.util.Collection)) function (KafkaConsumer).

Comment: `assign` seems to do the job indeed but it is incompatible with `subscribe`. Doesn't Kafka have an automatic load-balancing? As a workaround, I thought of creating as many partitions as my message batch size (16). Thus the slowest machine would slow things down for at most one message.

Comment: From my perspective the load balancing logic implemented in Kafka is not based on the performance of the consumers, is only based on the amount of consumers and partitions, you can control the partitions where the messages are published in the producer side or you can reassign partitions in the consumer side.

The last option you have (this is more a workaround than anything else) and following with my 4 partitions example is to spawn 3 processing processes in the fast machine and 1 on the slow one so you will force Kafka to follow your desired behavior.

Comment: yeah, launch #processes based on cpu count